# Avoid generating a new PDF ID with each compilation

Tags: hyperref

I want to create reproducible PDFs with lualatex, so if no code to the change took place, two compilation runs should yield the same identical PDF. I was able to set the CreationDate and ModDate using hyperref, overwriting the ID however has no effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
    Author={Just me},
    Title={My title},
    CreationDate={D:20222145000000},
    ModDate={D:20222145000000},
    ID = {6D2C23D7481FB94ACFBDA10EA47F3CB9},
  }
}

\begin{document}

Hallo

\end{document}
```

Comment: set the environment variable SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH

Comment: Related: I've just learned what it is from this very nice page on the subject, for beginners like me.

Answer (score 4):

With the new pdfmanagement you can use

`\pdfmeta_set_regression_data:`. That is the command we are using in the pdf tests.

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdfmeta_set_regression_data:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hallo

\end{document}
```

Without it you can add

```
   \tex_pdfvariable:D trailerid
     {[~
       <2350CAD05F8A7AF0AA4058486855344F>~
       <2350CAD05F8A7AF0AA4058486855344F>~
     ]}
```

to set the trailerid.